Postfix recipient rewriting based on recipient_canonical and the file .forward in the user home directory
Before posting this question, I already do some search on Google, serverfault, etc. and don't find anything (related to postfix and .forward)
Postfix - address rewriting - reply all
https://superuser.com/questions/353488/regex-multiple-catch-all-setup-in-postfix
We have a new SMTP server which accept sending mail only to a specific recipient, example: xxx@enterprise.com
On Linux machine, the user
-is identified by his Unix-id (jdoe)
-the user have a file .forward in his home directory /home/jdoe/.forward which contains jdoe@enterprise.com
1.If I run the command like this
mail -s "SMTPTLS Test On $HOST" jdoe@enterprise.com  <<< "Test SMTPSEC-TLS work on $HOST"
->the mail is sent even if the user jdoe@enterprise.com dont exist
2.If I run the command like this
mail -s "SMTPTLS Test On $HOST" jdoe  <<< "Test SMTPSEC-TLS work on $HOST"
I got the message
smtp-server: 550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: not allowed
"/root/dead.letter" 11/366
. . . message not sent.
which is normal as the SMTP relay control the recipiend which must be xxx@enterprise.com
The answers/findings are related to something static, per example in recipient_canonical
/user1@domain.com/   jdoe@enterprise.com
Is there a way to configure postfix to rewrite the recipient address based on user home directory file /home/userX/.forward ?
ie replacing jdoe by jdoe@enterprise.com, jane.doe by jane.doe@enterprise.com, etc depending on the user Unix-id and what it's set in the user home directory .forward file ?!?
Thks&BstRgds
Charles
